# How to add "where" condition to Zend Lucene search engine?

Tags: php, zend-framework

There is some code of searching using Zend Lucene:

```
$index = new Zend_Search_Lucene(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.'.$this->index_file));
$results = $index->find('PHP');
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    echo $result->name;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

It works correct. But now I need to add "where" condition to search: "WHERE vacancy_state=1". How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create query. You can do this as a text or use query API (ofc vancy_state has to be in your index):

```
title:"PHP" AND vacancy_state:1
```

or using API should be something like this:

```
    $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();
    $query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('PHP'), true);
    $query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term(1, 'vacancy_state'), true);
    $index->find($query);
```

OR

```
    $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();
    $term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('PHP');
    $subquery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($term);
    $query->addSubquery($subquery, true);
    $term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term(1, 'vacancy_state');
    $subquery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($term);
    $query->addSubquery($subquery, true);
```